# How to print a message if the do while loop condition is not met

Tags: java, int, joptionpane, do-while

How would I print a message saying "Error: you have to enter a number between 0 and 5", then allowing the user to input again

```
 int number;
 do 
  {
     String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
     number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
  } while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method which alters your original code the least is as follows:

```
int number;
do {
    String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
    number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
    if((number < 0) || (number > 5) {
        //show error message
        continue;  //continue isn't absolutely necessary here, but perhaps for readability
    }
} while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
```

Although I find this a little clunky and redundant, you're essentially checking the same condition twice.  I'd go with a method more like the following:

```
int number;
String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
while(true) {
    number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
    if((number >= 0 && number <= 5)) {
        //show error message and prompt for another input
        contine; //As with before, continue isn't necessary here, but could add readability
    } else /*input was good*/ { break; /*exit while loop*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like this. I used a regular expression to prevent a NumberFormatExcption.

```
int number = -1;
do 
{
   String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
   if( textinput.match("0*[0-5]") {
     number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
   }
   else {
     System.out.println("Error");
   }
} while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest the questioner use Regex, when they're not already using it, you should check the Regex for yourself.  This user may be completely unfamiliar with Regex, and Regex doesn't even necessarily give any advantage here that I can see.

Comment: You're are right, I should have checked it in the first place. But the advantage for the regex is it would prevent a NumberFormatException, thats all.

Comment: You should edit that point into the answer then (and check this yourself to be sure it works).  If you do those two, I'll upvote this answer.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);

    while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5)) {
        textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your number must be between 0 and 5!");
        number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
    }

    // do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be the least redundant and most readable way to write this:

```
int number;
while ((number = requestNumber()) < 0 || number > 5) {
    // Show your prompt
}
```

Declare this method somewhere:

```
private int requestNumber() {
    try {
        String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
        return Integer.parseInt(textinput); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

---

This is another option:

```
boolean valid;
int number;
do {
    String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
    number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
    if (number >= 0 && number <= 5) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        // Show your message here
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

It would avoid the recalculation of `number >= 0 && number <= 5` offered by the solutions of most of the answers.

---

The code in this answer was not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
        int number;
        if(nummber>0 && number<5)
        {
         do 
          {
             String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
             number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
          } while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
        }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("you have to enter a number between 0 to 5");
}
```

Comment: No.  This is going to only show the message once and only after he's exited the loop.  He clearly wants to stay in the loop until he's received a good value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;
Boolean bolContinue = true;
 do 
  {
     String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
     number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
     if (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5)) {
         //Log here
         bolContinue = false;
     }
  } while (bolContinue);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a prompt telling the user they had bad input.

Comment: Also, if the user failed once `bolContinue` will never be `true` again and the user will be stuck entering numbers for eternity while having the program lie telling them that the number is not between 0 and 5 :(

Comment: Oh, yea, that's a pretty good point.  I wasn't going to downvote for my observation, but I have to downvote for that one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as that.

```
int number;
do 
{
 String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
 number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
 if(!(number >= 0 && number <= 5))
     {
       System.out.println("Error: you have to enter a number between 0 and 5");
     }
} while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
```

Comment: This `if` fires only if the `while` will exit also, so you may as well just put the statement after the `while` and outside the `if`.  And either way, it's not doing what the question seems to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
int number;
     do 
      {
         String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
         number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
         if ( number > 5 || number  < 0)
         {
             System.out.println("Please enter number between 0 to 5");
             return;
         }
          } while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
}
```

Comment: `return`?  You mean `continue`?

Comment: Then you want `break`, but if you exit the loop, then you're not allowing the user to input another number, which is what the question asks.

Comment: Your `return` should instead be `break` if you're intending to exit the loop.  If you're intending to stay in the loop, it should be `continue`.  `return` isn't right here either way.  But as the question states, you should stay in the loop until the user enters a good value.